# Most efficient techniques to Show and Hide GameObject?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out how to evaluate which technique will be the best for a given series of problems. Here is an example:

- I have "Boxes" which are all consisting of a group of UI Buttons,
  text, icons. My goal is to give the user the possibility to Hide/Show
  these different elements as he/she wants.

---

From these guidelines, i can think of 4 different ways to deal with this:

1. Hide/Show these elements by Activating/Deactivating the gameobject
2. Destroy the gameobject/ Instantiate it when i need it again
3. Set the object to transparent or opaque
4. Set the position of the object in an unreachable place, or make its scale nanoscopic :P

---

The twist is that these boxes will be in a 3D space in which you can navigate, meaning they will be sometimes on screen and sometimes not. That has i guess its importance in order to determine which technique is best?

---

The question i have are:

1. Can I evaluate in advance which solution is going to be the most
   performance effective ? Is there some kind of conscensus which says
   that for example activate/Deactivate a game object is always slower
   than destroying instantiating it ?
2. Are there some lists about these conscensus somewhere ?
3. Are there other techniques in order to perform this task ?

I am guessing it is all about experience on working on different projects/tasks, though i find it difficult as a beginner to know *where/how to find the information*.

It feels like in a language, when there are several ways to say a same thing, but you are not sure how to formulate it, and even worse: when you don't know the existence of a word that would make it all shine.

If it was not for the Unity community/ Stack Overflow and so on, i would be in real trouble, so thanks again all for being here and be so helpful =).

Note: i have just stumbled on the profiler in unity and will look into what it can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best would be `no 1` which is `Activating/Deactivating` the `gameobject`, why ?

`no 2`, will cause `performance` issue if you are initiating a lots of object in one time. ex: firing a bullets. since you instantiate and destroying, it will create new memory allocation to store the each instantiate object and will find again the location of memory to clear it when you destroy.

`no 3`, will have `performance` issue and `colliding` issue, it will be a performance issue if there is a lot of object in the scene but then tranparent. because even it is transparent, GPU still need to render them. so it is the same whether you make it transparent or opaque. it will have colliding issue, if your object have collider but transparent. so it will collide with other object.

`no 4`, will have `performance` issue because if you scale them, i am afraid that you will break dynamic batching which will increase draw call. i also tried this method before and it is not good when your camera able to move `360`, imagine you hide it behind you, even it is far. when you look behind, you still can see them.

To easily `Activate/Deactivate` objects like you usually do(Instantiate/Destroy), you can try `Pooling System`. https://github.com/6ameDev/Advanced-Pooling-System

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and explanation Tengku. It was very informative... I am glad to get a new possibility with this pooling technique! Thanks a lot to you !

Comment: @Gynko Ok, don't forget to mark as answer if it help you. so other people who had same problem as you will get clear too.

Comment: Also, just to say it. You can find a lot of useful things and approaches with this book (out of many others, of course).
http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/